# searchMenuItem.getActionView() returning null

Tags: android

getActionView() is retuning null. What am i doing wrong?

I am extending Activity and using `android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="19"`

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"

    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/search"/>



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search");

    return true;
}
```

**manifest**

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Are you using `AppCompat` library? On which API level device?

Comment: @shkschneider yes i am using AppCompact and my device is API21

Comment: `android:actionViewClass` => `app:actionViewClass`  and `searchItem.getActionView()` => `MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem)` ... also consider to change `android.widget.SearchView` to `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` (as non compact version acts a little bit different on different APIs)

Comment: @Selvin exactly. Post that as an answer Sir :)

Comment: @Selvin that worked. thanks. please post it an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw that you have `app:showAsAction="always"` the `app` namespace means that you are using Appcompat v7 library ...

Appcompat library has it owns method for menu items as static method in `MenuCompat`/`MenuItemCompat` classes (and you should use 'em like instead `menu.methodXXX()` use `MenuCompat.methodXXX(menu)` )

Now, to define a `actionViewClass`(and others attributes added in api newer then 11) in menu you should use the `app` namespace for this instead `android` namespace

so `android:actionViewClass` should become `app:actionViewClass`

in the code you should use `MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem)` instead `searchItem.getActionView()`

remeber to add namespace `app` in root element of menu xml file like `xmlns:app ="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

also small hint (as you are using 11 as min sdk your code should works fine but ...) replace `android.widget.SearchView` to `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` as it(standard SearchView) not works in the same way on different API versions from 11 to newest one(also you will get method not found if you use methods added in API > 11 to SearchView on devce with API 11)