# why android.support.v7.widget.SearchView can not be shown on the actionbar?

Tags: android

[image]

After I clicked the search button, nothing happened. The search box does not occur.Below is my menu.xml.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
          android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_compose"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_compose"
          android:title="@string/action_compose"
           android:showAsAction="never"  />
</menu>
```

Although the search widget was not shown on the action bar, but there was no exception thrown until I added the following code in method ***onCreateOptionsMenu*** .

```
MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
```

The detailed exception is below.

```
01-19 14:17:00.222: W/ResourceType(2064): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
01-19 14:17:00.222: W/MenuInflater(2064): Cannot instantiate class: android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
01-19 14:17:00.222: W/MenuInflater(2064): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-19 14:17:00.222: W/MenuInflater(2064):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
01-19 14:17:00.222: W/MenuInflater(2064):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
01-19 14:17:00.222: W/MenuInflater(2064):   at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.newInstance(MenuInflater.java:514)
01-19 14:17:00.222: W/MenuInflater(2064):   at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(MenuInflater.java:471)
01-19 14:17:00.222: W/MenuInflater(2064):   at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(MenuInflater.java:493)
01-19 14:17:00.222: W/MenuInflater(2064):   at android.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:189)
01-19 14:17:00.222: W/MenuInflater(2064):   at android.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:110)
01-19 14:17:00.222: W/MenuInflater(2064):   at com.example.android.effectivenavigation.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:215)
01-19 14:17:00.222: W/MenuInflater(2064):   at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2820)
01-19 14:17:00.222: W/MenuInflater(2064):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:275)
01-19 14:17:00.222: W/MenuInflater(2064):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:548)
01-19 14:17:00.222: W/MenuInflater(2064):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:917)
01-19 14:17:00.222: W/MenuInflater(2064):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:258)
01-19 14:17:00.222: W/MenuInflater(2064):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
01-19 14:17:00.222: W/MenuInflater(2064):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-19 14:17:00.222: W/MenuInflater(2064):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
01-19 14:17:00.222: W/MenuInflater(2064):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
01-19 14:17:00.222: W/MenuInflater(2064):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-19 14:17:00.222: W/MenuInflater(2064):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-19 14:17:00.222: W/MenuInflater(2064):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
01-19 14:17:00.222: W/MenuInflater(2064):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
01-19 14:17:00.222: W/MenuInflater(2064): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
01-19 14:17:00.222: W/MenuInflater(2064):   at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1233)
01-19 14:17:00.222: W/MenuInflater(2064):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2598)
01-19 14:17:00.222: W/MenuInflater(2064):   at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1049)
01-19 14:17:00.222: W/MenuInflater(2064):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:412)
01-19 14:17:00.222: W/MenuInflater(2064):   at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:282)
01-19 14:17:00.222: W/MenuInflater(2064):   at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:268)
01-19 14:17:00.222: W/MenuInflater(2064):   at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:264)
01-19 14:17:00.222: W/MenuInflater(2064):   ... 21 more
```

Comment: Are you attempting to use the `appcompat-v7` action bar backport, or the native action bar? Right now, what you have is a blend of both, which will not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [searchMenuItem.getActionView() returning null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27903361/searchmenuitem-getactionview-returning-null) check from the part `Now, to define a actionViewClass...` also if you are using proguard you have to tell it to leave `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` alone with `-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }`

Comment: what I imported was import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

Comment: I used    the appcompat-v7.

Comment: what you have is a blend of both..> what does it mean?

Comment: One more point, my sample was downloaded from official training site,called EffectiveNavigation. I only added a search action like above.

Answer (score 6):

> I used the appcompat-v7

Then you should have not done this:

> what I imported was import android.app.ActionBar;

That is the native action bar, not the backport. Also:

- you need to inherit from `ActionBarActivity`, not `FragmentActivity`, and
- you need to change `android:showAsAction` and `android:actionViewClass` to `app:showAsAction` and `app:actionViewClass`

For example, [here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppCompat/SearchView) that uses `SearchView` from `appcompat-v7`.

The menu resource from that project is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        android:title="@string/filter">
    </item>

</menu>
```

Note the use of the `app` prefixes for `actionViewClass` and `showAsAction`.

Comment: thanks. I have a question. Why google developed some classes that only located in v4 or v7, like FragmentActivity,ActionBarDrawerToggle.  IMO, every class in v4 or v7 should firstly located in native version.

Comment: @liamxu: `FragmentActivity` does not need to exist in the native version, as `Activity` knows about fragments. However, while Google may own a time machine, they have not used it to go back in time and add fragments to versions of `Activity` that existed prior to API Level 11; hence, the backport needs an `Activity` subclass that knows about fragments. Other stuff, like `ViewPager` and `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, do not exist in the native API in part to make it easier for us to upgrade the versions of those classes that our apps use, rather than being dependent upon the OS level of the device.